# What Transformations have been taken?

Tags: sas, data-science, transformation, data-analysis

I am a novice SAS user and was wondering if anyone could help me with identifying all the transformations from the transformations statistics sheet from SAS Enterprise Miner 13.2. For example, number bank balance variable has been transformed to "PWR_cr_bb" and team variable has been transformed into TG_team. However I am not sure what transformations these are referring to, if any at all.

[image]

I am aware of the log and square root transformations. But I am not aware of what the others are referring to, illuminated in this post (please also see image for clarification).

Cheers

Comment: My guess is those variables without any formula are simply copied.  They probably appear on the report/list so you can see the values of other fields in that table, like the number of missing values.

Comment: Yeah, that's right. The original variables (input) have been transformed as denoted by output. I was asked what transformations have been done based on all of this information, in the table. I can see the square root and log transformations i.e. I know what they are. But I don't know what the acronym PWR (maybe power transformation) or TG stands for. Surely they are transformations as denoted by output, and if so, what are they called?